# Repeat many times without macro?

Tags: macro, repeated-commands

Is there a way to repeat a normal mode sequence n times without making a macro for it?

I thought `5:norm` would be able to do that, but that actually runs the normal mode sequence once for each line of the next 5 lines, it doesn't run the normal mode sequence 5 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing "macro" and "recording", here. The result of a recording is indeed a macro, but the RHS of a mapping and the argument of `:normal` are also macros.

`:normal` being an Ex command, it is naturally line-oriented, which implies a certain way to handle `[count]`.

```
:normal daw
```

deletes "a word", but:

```
5:normal daw
```

deletes "a word" on the current line and the four that follow.

But there is a way out of this. You know the `@q` you use to play back the macro stored in register `q`? Well, if you just executed:

```
:normal daw
```

then the `:` register contains:

```
:normal daw
```

and you can do `@:` to execute it again or `5@q` to do it five times.

---

Of course, `5daw` would have been easier, here, but that is all I could come up with… without you providing a proper example.